# iMessage from IMac to IPhone

Tags: iphone, imac, messages

I'm having difficulty with the iMessage app in the sense that I would like to be able to send an iMessage from my IMac @home to my IPhone @On the road?  How do I do this without creating a different Apple ID for both? They are both mine - but I want to be able to communicate between the two.  Is this possible?  Thanks. Theresa

Comment: It's not possible

Answer (score 1):

hmmm… initially I thought this couldn't be done, however.

From messages, start a new conversation, from the top right icon. Start typing your own name until you can select your iMessage-capable account, accept then type the message.
Send.
A few seconds later the message will arrive on both devices & you can then converse with 'yourself' - though it will all appear in both columns, as though you were actually talking to 'yourself'.

Looks odd - but it works.

Tested initiating on both iPhone & Mac. Both work.

iPhone seems to generate multiple conversations for some reason, but the Mac keeps it inline.
Minor inconvenience, I'd say, for the benefits of being able to talk to yourself ;-)

Comment: Yes Tetsujin, I appreciate your answer, however I am aware that I can talk to "myself." I guess I was somehow asking how I could assign my Mac a unique number.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: not without 2 separate IDs