# Is it possible to test iMessage functionality without another person?

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

I'm trying to switch cell carriers and I want to make sure that both iMessage and SMS text work on the new one. I can trigger an SMS anytime I want through any number of websites with 2FA. Is there a way to get a test iMessage sent to you other than asking a friend through a different channel to text you?

Comment: Skype has a “test account” that you can call to verify functionality and call quality.  This sounds like it would be a good idea here as well.

Comment: Similar solution to a different problem [ultimately not what the OP wanted] - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158740/imessage-from-imac-to-iphone/158743#158743

Comment: Try texting yourself it works a treat. Delete it afterwards cause youll be confused why it came from you weeks later.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can send a message to yourself. I've used this when having trouble with messages. You'll have received messages on the left and the sent ones on the right just as it is with other people.

Comment: I honestly never thought of chatting with myself...then again, I’d probably lose the argument.  +1 for a simple solution that’ll get funny looks from a therapist.  :-)

Comment: This solution actually works in many situations. Want to test sending/receiving emails? Send to yourself! Want to check if the network is working because you didn't receive an SMS? Send one to yourself! Want to check that your network is working (within reason)? Ping yourself!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Sending an email to yourself is not sufficient to test an email system as most MTAs will route mail internally (e.g. if you use Gmail and sending an email to another Gmail user - the message won't enter the Internet at all) - some e-mail systems may detect emails-to-self and just copy the message directly from your Outbox to your Inbox without putting it through routing at all - let alone test that your DNS MX records are working or that your sending (or receiving) SMTP server is functional.

Comment: @Dai You missed the point ... It isn't to test the email system, it's to test the client-side email configuration, to make sure that the email application is sending and receiving emails properly. Server-side doesn't matter at all, as I assume a fully working system. I've had troubles configuring emails on iPhones and many more with the Mac's mail app. Just sending a simple email to yourself helps to make sure you have configured everything correctly.